# How do smartphone cameras focus?

Tags: focus, cameraphones

I'm curious, when I focus my DSLR or my pocket camera the lens moves back and forth changing the distance from the sensor. Does this really happen inside my smartphone?

Comment: BTW the answer is **Yes**.